Arabic text appeared correctly in some case while not in other using itext7
This code reads a PDF template and adds text to it. Arabic text in the first image is copied from a word template to the database, while the second is read from already existing data. why this behavior?
database is MySql table charset is umbt8mb4 and the collation is umbt8mb4_09000_ai_ci
When selecting open value in editor in workbench the first input appears as squares and the second appears correct, also they have different binary values. So could itext show Arabic correctly depending on its encoding?
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PdfUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(docsDownloadConfig.getStatementTemplatePath()));

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

String arString = user.getName;
document.add(new Paragraph(reorderArabicText(arString)).setFont(getFont()));

document.close();
return baos;

private static String reorderArabicText(String text) 
{
    Pattern arabicPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u0750-\\u077F\\u08A0-\\u08FF\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70-\\uFEFF]+");

    if (arabicPattern.matcher(text).find()) 
    {
        Bidi bidi = new Bidi(text, Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        bidi.setReorderingMode(Bidi.REORDER_INVERSE_NUMBERS_AS_L);
        return bidi.writeReordered(Bidi.DO_MIRRORING);
    } 
    else 
        return text;
}

private static PdfFont getFont() throws IOException 
{
    return PdfFontFactory.createFont("images/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>75.1</version>
</dependency>



When using the below lines to check the charset, both return "UTF-8":
CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
detector.setText(yourStr.getBytes());
detector.detect();


you also need the typography module, which is the product pdfCalligraph.

but why same text from different sources appear differently, despite not using PDF calligraph

i mean there is a way to show text correctly if discover the reason.

As you appear to use the same code in both cases, the difference most likely is to be found in the inputs. Have you analyzed the contents of your input strings character-by-character?

when selecting open value in editor in workbench the first input appears as squares and the second appears correct, so could itext show Arabic correctly depending on its encoding?

It looks like this editor determines the encoding automatically by the text itself but not by any directive. Such automation makes mistakes sometimes. I have much experience with my native Cyrillic encodings.

how can i analyze the content in both cases?@mkl
